# knockout.js - modify DOM in current item in list (expand list item subsection) using templates

Tags: list, templates, dom, knockout.js, handler

In this example I want to use knockout.js to allow the "Expand" link to be clicked and have its text changed to "Collapse".  I also want to set the make the jobDetails section visible.  This is a very general question of how to get knockout.js to specifically modify the DOM of the "current" item in a list using a click handler.

```
<script type="text/html" id="job-template">
    <div class="jobContainer">
        <label data-bind="text: JobTitle"></label> 
        <label data-bind="text: CompanyName"></label>
        <div class="jobDetails">
            <label data-bind="text: City"></label>
            <label data-bind="text: State"></label>
        </di>
    <div>
        <a class="expand" href="#" data-bind="click: ???">Expand</a>        
    </div>
    </div>    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very straight forward with KO. Here's a simple way to do it. FYI I had to fix your markup slightly.

```
<div>
    <div class="jobContainer">
        <label data-bind="text: JobTitle"></label>
        <label data-bind="text: CompanyName"></label>
        <div class="jobDetails" data-bind="visible: expanded">
            <label data-bind="text: City"></label>
            <label data-bind="text: State"></label>
        </div>
    <div>
    <a class="expand" href="#" data-bind="click: toggle, text: linkLabel">Expand</a>        
</div>   


var viewModel = function() {
    this.JobTitle = ko.observable("some job");
    this.CompanyName = ko.observable("some company");
    this.City = ko.observable("some city");
    this.State = ko.observable("some state");

    this.someValue = ko.observable().extend({ defaultIfNull: "some default" });

    this.expanded = ko.observable(false);

    this.linkLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.expanded() ? "collapse" : "expand";
    }, this);      

    this.toggle = function () {
        this.expanded(!this.expanded());
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/XAzW6/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is exactly what I'm looking for, however, I'm getting a JavaScript error in my firebug console telling me that 'toggle' is not defined.  Is this entire chunk is inside a knockout.js html template?

Comment: If it's being displayed as part of a foreach in the template binding try using $parent.toggle. This will reference the parent viewmodel.

Comment: I moved the code out of a template into a wrapping <div data-bind="foreach: jobs"> tag, but for some reason the jobDetails visibility doesn't receive a callback to expand.  The expand/collapse text is changing but the visibilty of the details does not toggle properly.

Comment: So I figured out the problem.  I had a "display: none;" css property on the jobDetails class, which I guess overrides the visibility of the  observable in all cases.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AdamLevitt - Cool. I actually just knocked up an example of the foreach with an item class (http://jsfiddle.net/Ajq6F/1/) and using a parent handler function (http://jsfiddle.net/DJ6JA/1/). If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: So the problem now that I'm seeing is that when I click "expand" it expands EVERY single jobDetails section in my list.  How can I confine it to just the "current" item's jobDetails section?

Comment: Oops! Looks like you may have already answered this part.  Looking at it now.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: More related questions!  What if I want to put an up/down arrow icon in the background of the <a> tag, where the down arrow shows when the link's class="expand" and the up arrow shows when the link's class="collapse".  The question is, how can I swap the anchor's class? I found this method, but it seems like a slight hack: <a class="expand" href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.toggle, text: linkLabel, attr: { 'class': linkLabel.toLowerCase() }">Expand</a>